# Photo size in getPhotoUrl() method Google Identity toolkit

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I did the login using Google Identity Toolkit, I have noticed that the class GitkitUser.UserProfile retrieves the photo url, but is too small. The google documentation do not say anything about photo size.

https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/reference/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitUser.UserProfile.html#getPhotoUrl()

**For example with Facebook login, the getPhotoUrl() method returns:**

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12651146_10208004779813340_3124516205553866664_n.jpg?oh=efa817d10aaf9d184a767bae81a71071&oe=576850AD

**For example with Gmail login, the getPhotoUrl() method returns:**

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-5XFRyKHh7Os/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABIo/Trf7GjTnFec/s96-c/photo.jpg

Deleting /s96-c (or replace to /s200-c) in the Gmail photo url appears big, but I need a workaround to Facebook photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for android was obtain the federatedId and after that call:

http://graph.facebook.com/{federatedId}/picture?type=large

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        client = GitkitClient.newBuilder(this, new GitkitClient.SignInCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onSignIn(IdToken idToken, GitkitUser user) {
                DataStorage.getInstance().setLastToken(idToken.getTokenString());
                Configuration config = Configuration.fromMetaData(AppInfo.getAppInfo(LoginActivity.this).metaData);
                ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(config.getApiKey(), AppInfo.getAppInfo(LoginActivity.this), config.getServerWidgetUrl());
                final GetAccountInfo.Request request = apiClient.newGetAccountInfoRequest(idToken);

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        GetAccountInfo.Response accountInfo = request.execute();

                        JSONArray users = accountInfo.getJsonResponse().optJSONArray("users");
                        JSONObject user = users == null ? null : users.optJSONObject(0);
                        String email = user == null ? null : user.optString("email");
                        if (email != null) {
                            JSONArray providerUserInfo = user.optJSONArray("providerUserInfo");
                            if (providerUserInfo != null && providerUserInfo.length() != 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < providerUserInfo.length(); ++i) {
                                    JSONObject userInfo = providerUserInfo.optJSONObject(i);
                                    if (userInfo != null) {
                                        try {
                                            String userInfoString = userInfo.getString("federatedId");
                                            if(userInfoString.contains("facebook.com")) {
                                                int lastSlash = userInfoString.lastIndexOf("/");
                                                if(lastSlash != -1) {
                                                    String federatedIdFacebook = userInfoString.substring(lastSlash + 1, userInfoString.length());
                                                    Log.i("federatedIdFacebook", federatedIdFacebook);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            Log.e("LoginActivity", e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();


            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the idToken to get the User's identifier at IDP (facebook id).

See users[].providerUserInfo[].federatedId at https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/getAccountInfo

And then use the facebookId to get the large account picture, with

http://graph.facebook.com/{facebookId}/picture?type=large

Comment: This solution is for web, I am in android I would like a directly solution. But you give me an idea, requires some changes but could work.