# How to get a Google profile image with specific resolution on Android

Tags: google-signin, googlesigninaccount

There seems to be no direct way to query a users google profile image with a specific resolution on Android. The documented approach is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

That approach provides an image URL which is of a low resolution (using: GoogleSignInAccount's getPhotoUrl() method).

The corresponding approach on iOS does have a way to get the profile image by specifying a resolution as mentioned here:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data#a8e229bffe211894473058c4ba247553c

The workaround suggested in one of the stackoverflow posts is to do a string replacement in the retrieved URL to get a larger image. Link: [Photo size in getPhotoUrl() method Google Identity toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382965/photo-size-in-getphotourl-method-google-identity-toolkit)

Is there a better way to get a higher resolution google profile image on Android for Google Sign-in?